# Get Intercom User_Id and pass as javascript variable

Tags: javascript, api, intercom

I'm trying to embed an Intercom widget on a static webpage, but then pull user data to populate javascript variables to dynamically populate content on the page. Mainly, I need the user_id and email of the logged in user.

Can anyone provide an example of how to set a javascript variable "userId" (that I can then pull into a separate function on the page) to equal that of the Intercom 'user_id'?

Comment: Depends on how the page stores this. Is it a cookie? Is it localStorage?

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the same issue and I also couldn't find any official intercom API to retrieve the user ID of a "lead" user. The visitor ID is not very helpful unfortunately: many intercom APIs wont accept it and return "not found", once a visitor has been converted to a lead or a user. The only way I was able tor retrieve the user ID in the frontend is by using the same internal API as the intercom widget does:

```
const INTERCOM_APP_ID = 'XXXXXXXX';
const visitorId = window.Intercom('getVisitorId');
const apiResponse = await fetch('https://api-iam.intercom.io/messenger/web/ping', {
   credentials: 'include',
   method: 'POST',
   body: `app_id=${INTERCOM_APP_ID}&v=3&user_data={"anonymous_id":"${visitorId}"}`,
   headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(res => res.json())

console.log(apiResponse.user)
```

this will return an object with user id and some additional information:

```
{
  // the intercom user ID you are looking for
  id: "6294666ff2e8e2xxxxxxxxxx",
  type: "user",
  role: "visitor_role",
  locale: "en",
  has_conversations: false,
  // the "visitor ID" (painful to deal with. use the ID above)
  anonymous_id: "2db7de4b-320c-4e4a-af30-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  country_code: "ch",
  home_screen_slots: (2) […],
  new_session: true,
  help_center_require_search: false,
  … }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below method. This is just an example.

```html
<script>
  #get the user id
  user_id = "<get the user id of the logged in user>";
  Intercom('boot', {  
    'app_id': 'abc12345',  
    'email': 'john.doe@example.com',
    'created_at': 1234567890,
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'user_id': user_id #user_id of the logged in user
  });
</script>
```

Intercom Javascript API - [Link](https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/intercom-javascript)

Comment: Subhrajyoti,
Thank you for the response, however this doesn't answer my issue. I need to dynamically pull the information to populate the email, name, and user_id. I can't figure out how to do that part. I have this function in place, but obviously cannot have hard-coded user data in place. Any thoughts on how to pull the user data itself?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Pulling the user information depends on what you are using to log the user in. Google your framework and how user management is done in the framework.

Comment: Intercom IS pulling the user data in properly (I can tell by testing the chat opening and greeting me by name). I just don't know how to properly GET this data to populate variables in the script (which I then want to pass into a separate, custom function). And I cannot find documentation on the proper syntax to pull it (ie: "Intercom.user_id")